# How to send S3 input file name that after it(S3 file) is processed in AWS Glue job to AWS Lambda using a Cloud Watch event?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue

An AWS Lambda Function(`lambda_fns1`) get triggered whenever a file (`sample_file`) is uploaded to an S3 bucket (`raw_data_bucket`)

Say path is `s3://raw_data_bucket/client1/data/sample_file`

This Lambda Function (`lambda_fns1`) then triggers an AWS Glue Job(`glue_job`) for file processing.

**Note:** Glue Job is part of the entire Glue Workflow. Half a dozen jobs get completed before the CloudWatch Event to start.

Once this Glue is completed, using a Cloud Watch Event Rule (`cloud_event_rule`) triggering another Lambda function(`lambda_fns2`).

```
[lambda_fns1] -> [[Glue Workflow(glue_job)]] -> [cloud_event_rule] -> [lambda_fns2]
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYydZ5JLtQo

Initially, there had only 1 client we hardcoded these values but there are many clients. Now I need to pass the following details to `lambda_fns2`.  How to do this?

```
{
'tenant': 'client1',
'path': 's3://raw_data_bucket/client1/data/sample_file'
}
```

Comment: How do you call the lambda after the glue job finished? keep the path of the s3 file and return it to the lambda.

Comment: My bad forgot to mention Cloud Watch Event Rule!

Comment: It looks hard to pass that argument into the second lambda. You can try to set your job name as the s3 path and send it to the second lambda but this is not a regular way. When the glue job is finished, invoke lambda2 with specific event form by aws sdk that is the only idea I can think.

Comment: Why not call second lambda from glue job using boto3 lambda APis?

Comment: @SandeepFatangare - Good idea! But can't do that as my client does not hardcoded values in code.

Comment: OK, my assumption is that you do not have access to glue job code or do not have permission to modify it but you can modify lambda code. In that case, you may write config file (e.g. config.py) containing s3 details (e.g. s3_path="s3://raw_data_bucket/client1/data/sample_file"). In your second lambda, use config file to get s3 details.

Comment: @SandeepFatangare - Thanks. Imagine 100 - 200 jobs are running at time and each job takes its own time to finish.
At first lambda, I write 100 config files. Say after a min, 10 jobs are done and 10 config files might be there for lambda to pick up. The second lambda has to find which 10 out 100 files to be processed  :(

Comment: why 100 files? You should write one config file containing config details of all jobs e.g. s3_path[job_name] = "s3://raw_data_bucket/client1/data/sample_file". You get job name from cloudwatch event, you can use it to point to correct s3_path